# How to use both a field separator and ignore lines in awk without piping?

Tags: awk, pipe, cut

Is it possible to get rid of the cut command in this line, and without piping to another command?

`awk 'NR > 1 {print l}{l=$2}' filename | cut -d':' -f2`

---

**Details, if you want or need them:**

[This is a question of interest than necessity - I can/did use `cut` like above to get the job done easily]

I was able to get the 2nd column while ignoring the last line of the file with `NR > 1{print l}{l=$2}`.

Basically it's a flat file database (note the last line of non-data content), and I need the values of each `field1`:

```
$ cat file
1    field1:value1    field2:value2    ...
                   .
                   .
                   .
N    field1:value1    field2:value2    ...
other.parseable info.that is.unnecessary to.me
```

Trying the `-F` flag doesn't work  because it seems that it changes the column numbers since it is doing the "cut" first:

```
$ awk -F ':' 'NR > 1 {print l}{l=$2}' file
value1   field2
value1   field2
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `split` function of `awk`.

```
awk '{ split($2, var, /:/ ); print var[2] }'
```

Or use multiple delimiters:

```
awk -F'[ :]+' '{print $3}'
```